# While compiling with --fast flag, I ran into a error I am not sure of

Tags: chapel

I am using the `--fast` flag the first time I tried I got this error

```
warning: --specialize was set, but CHPL_TARGET_CPU is 'unknown'. 
If you want any specialization to occur please set CHPL_TARGET_CPU to a proper value.
```

so I input this command

```
export CHPL_TARGET_CPU=aarch64
```

since it is the architecture of my Jetson Nano board

then I got this error:

```
/home/chico/chapel-1.20.0/third-party/gasnet/Makefile.setup:6: /home/chico/chapel-1.20.0/third-party/gasnet/install/linux64-gnu-aarch64-none/substrate-udp/seg-everything/nodbg/include/udp-
conduit/udp-par.mak: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/home/chico/chapel-1.20.0/third-party/gasnet/install/linux64-gnu-aarch64-none/substrate-udp/seg-everything/nodbg/include/udp-conduit/udp-par.mak'. Stop
.error: compiling generated source
```

I do not get an executable after trying to compile my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is a (poor) indication that the Chapel runtime has not been built for your current `CHPL_*` configuration, where in this case, the change to `CHPL_TARGET_CPU` is the issue.  If you do `cd $CHPL_HOME && make` (or `gmake`) while CHPL_TARGET_CPU is still set, the runtime will be rebuilt for your current settings and when recompiling the Chapel program, the error should go away.

Note that multiple builds of Chapel can co-exist simultaneously with different CHPL_TARGET_CPU settings.